# Retrieve all Products in a set of Categories - uni-directional and use pagination?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

in our application we have a uni-directional relation like Category / Product

A Category has many Products, but a product does not know in what categories it is placed.
Now i would like to retrieve all products for a set of categories and use the params for pagination
I seem to hit a wall and have no clue on how to achieve this.

example:

```
class Category {
    static hasMany = [products: Product]
}

class Product {
}
```

Any hints on how i could achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use static hasMany = [categories:Category] in Product?

Comment: I am trying to make the domain model as stupid as possible this to enforce a strict implementation. I have no problem in introducing the hasmany relation, so if that is the way to go then that would be ok with me. I am still eager to learn how this can be done without adding the additional hasMany relation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using HQL like:

```
def query = "select product from Category category join category.products product where     category.name in :categories"
def books = Category.executeQuery(query, [categories:['Fantasy']])

println books
```